# Accessing Cache Variable created from client side from the Server Side ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a client side script which creates a cache variable on text input

```
  jQuery(function () {
            var inputBuffer = "";
            jQuery("#divEditorBody").keypress(function (event) {
                // Collect input that is not being processed by an input/textarea field
                inputBuffer += String.fromCharCode(event.charCode);
                localStorage['editorCache'] = inputBuffer;
            });
            jQuery("input,textarea").focus(function (event) {
                // Append buffered input to text field
                jQuery(this).val(jQuery(this).val() + inputBuffer);
                localStorage['editorCache'] = inputBuffer;
            });
            jQuery("input,textarea").blur(function (event) {
                /// Append buffered input to text field
                jQuery(this).val(jQuery(this).val() + inputBuffer);
                localStorage['editorCache'] = inputBuffer;
            });
        });
```

Then I a m trying to access it from the server side as below

```
HTMLBody = Convert.ToString(Cache["editorCache"]) == "" ? editorBody.InnerText : Convert.ToString(Cache["editorCache"]);
```

But this will always empty string as

```
 Convert.ToString(Cache["editorCache"]) == ""
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Because you're storing it in the *local* storage of the browser. The server does not have access to that information.

Comment: Why you didn't use asp hidden field. You can update hidden field value using jQuery and then access it from server side.

Comment: Local storage is exactly that. Storage on that user's browser. `Cache` is an application wide, server side storage mechanism, shared by all users.` You need a mechanism to get that client side information server side. This can be done via posting a form to the server or via AJAX techniques. You will also want to learn about server-side `session` storage.

Comment: @Thili77 I am using a DevExpress callback to trigger an autosave on the page. I needed this because the saving function is running on a thread and that thread cannot access the UI threads values therefore the thread which do the autosave fails to track the changes i made in the textarea. so I though I'd use caching to save data and retrieve that data from the thread which save the data

Comment: My next question is: when do you want to access this data server side? On form post? What does the user/client have to do to trigger access to this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out the issue I faced was the textarea input which was inside the div tag is not being synchronized so the textarea do not have the values on the server side.So once i did enable the synchronization I've managed to access the textarea text from the server side. so I didn't require caching at all.